# Field expression not allowed for generic SObject

Tags: apex, class

I am writing my trigger in an apex class, while doing this i am facing the error:

> 'Field expression not allowed for generic SObject at line 15 column
>   94'.

Here is my apex class:

```
public class updateCaseHandler 
{

public static void updatecaseclosed(list<Case> newlist)
{
         Map<Id, Task> taskMap = new Map<Id, Task>();


    for(Task t : [SELECT Id, WhatId FROM Task WHERE IsClosed=false AND WhatId IN :trigger.newMap.keySet()])
    {
        taskMap.put(t.WhatId, t);
    }


    for(Case c : Trigger.new)
    {

        if(taskMap.containsKey(c.Id) && c.IsClosed && c.IsClosed != Trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id).IsClosed)
            c.addError('Case Cannot be closed with open tasks');
    } 
    }
}
```

Any idea? how can i avoid this error.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you have `trigger.new` inside a class? I'm not sure with that

Comment: yes @highfive, we can access them in classes. not best way though!

Comment: Why not just pass the trigger.new / old Map to the method and use em ? That will take care of all the typecasting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to typecast the variables:

```
    public class updateCaseHandler  {

        public static void updatecaseclosed(list<Case> newlist) {
                 Map<Id, Task> taskMap = new Map<Id, Task>();


            for(Task t : [SELECT Id, WhatId FROM Task WHERE IsClosed=false AND WhatId IN :trigger.newMap.keySet()]) {
                taskMap.put(t.WhatId, t);
            }

            List<Case> lstNewCases = Trigger.new;

            for(Case c : lstNewCases) {

                Case objOldCase = (Case) Trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id);

                if(taskMap.containsKey(c.Id) && 
                    c.IsClosed && 
                    c.IsClosed != objOldCase.IsClosed) {

                    c.addError('Case Cannot be closed with open tasks');
                } 
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the Trigger is on Cases? Try casting `Trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id).IsClosed` to Case:
`((Case)Trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id)).IsClosed`

Answer (score 1):

Try with this, i changed Trigger.new by newlist!

```
public class updateCaseHandler 
{
    public static void updatecaseclosed(list<Case> newlist)
    {
        Map<Id, Task> taskMap = new Map<Id, Task>();

    for(Task t : [SELECT Id, WhatId FROM Task WHERE IsClosed=false AND WhatId IN :trigger.newMap.keySet()])
    {
        taskMap.put(t.WhatId, t);
    }


    for(Case c : newlist)
    {

        if(taskMap.containsKey(c.Id) && c.IsClosed && c.IsClosed != Trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id).IsClosed)
            c.addError('Case Cannot be closed with open tasks');
    } 
    }
}
```